# Error using fileinput to add a line in a batch of text files

Tags: python, file-io

I have a (Windows) directory with about 200 CSV text files, all in the same format, but missing a header row.  I want to iterate through them and add a header row.  I am using the Python window within ArcGIS.  When I run the following code I get

RuntimeError: input() already active

Code:

```
>>> flist = os.listdir(directory)
... headers = ['id','lat','time','long','event','heading']
... for f in flist:
...     for line in fileinput.input(flist, inplace=1):
...         if fileinput.isfirstline():
...             print ','.join(headers)
...         print line,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `for line in fileinput.input(flist, inplace=1):`

You are already in a loop over the items in `flist`. Probably you mean `fileinput.input(f,...)`

Comment: Hey thanks!  I ended up using windows powershell to do what I needed, but I just revisited to see if I could figure out the Python way, and your answer did the trick, that was exactly the problem!  Thanks again.